# How do I set a JLabel's background color?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

In my `JPanel`, I set the background of a `JLabel` to a different color. I can see the word "Test" and it's blue, but the background doesn't change at all. How can I get it to show?

```
this.setBackground(Color.white);
JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
label.setForeground(Color.blue);
label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
this.add(label);
```

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Use

```
label.setOpaque(true);
```

Otherwise the background is not painted, since the default of `opaque` is `false` for `JLabel`.

From the [JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque%28boolean%29):

> If true the component paints every pixel within its bounds. Otherwise, the component may not paint some or all of its pixels, allowing the underlying pixels to show through.

For more information, read the Java Tutorial [How to Use Labels](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Answer (score 42):

The JLabel background is transparent by default.
Set the opacity at true like that:

```
label.setOpaque(true);
```

Answer (score 16):

You must set the setOpaque(true) to true other wise the background will not be painted to the form. I think from reading that if it is not set to true that it will paint some or not any of its pixels to the form. The background is transparent by default which seems odd to me at least but in the way of programming you have to set it to true as shown below.

```
      JLabel lb = new JLabel("Test");
      lb.setBackground(Color.red);
      lb.setOpaque(true); <--This line of code must be set to true or otherwise the
```

From the JavaDocs

setOpaque

```
public void setOpaque(boolean isOpaque)
  If true the component paints every pixel within its bounds. Otherwise, 
  the component may not paint some or all of its pixels, allowing the underlying 
  pixels to show through.
  The default value of this property is false for JComponent. However, 
  the default value for this property on most standard JComponent subclasses 
   (such as JButton and JTree) is look-and-feel dependent.

Parameters:
isOpaque - true if this component should be opaque
See Also:
isOpaque()
```

Answer (score 6):

For the Background, make sure you have imported `java.awt.Color` into your package.

In your `main` method, i.e. `public static void main(String[] args)`, call the already imported method:

```
JLabel name_of_your_label=new JLabel("the title of your label");
name_of_your_label.setBackground(Color.the_color_you_wish);
name_of_your_label.setOpaque(true);
```

NB: Setting opaque will affect its visibility. Remember the case sensitivity in Java.