# How can I set the cell background color in a SortableTable?

Tags: java, swing

How set cell background color in a SortableTable?

Comment: Post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [cell renderers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (if you have a JTable in mind)

Answer (score 1):

If the component is a `JLabel`, it has to be opaque, but anyone can make that [mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314). :-)