# JPanel said to be opaque what does that mean?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

In Swing JPanel said to be opaque, what does that mean?

Also how JPanel VS JComponent compared in relation to opaque?

Please explain if possible in simple terms, hence i am not very experienced in GUI programming.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Opaque has a very specific meaning in Swing - it means that the component fully paints the full area within its bounds (see the [setOpaque javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(boolean)))

This is used primarily to determine whether it is necessary to repaint components behind the current component.

- If isOpaque is true, it is
  unnecessary to repaint anything
  behind the component (since it would
  just be overwritten), hence such
  background drawing may be omitted as
  an optimisation.
- If isOpaque is false, then it indicates
  that the component is implementing some transparency
  effects - e.g. drawing a component that has a semi-transparent window in the middle, or drawing a non-rectangular component

If you are creating your own JComponent and setOpaque to true but do not honour the contract (i.e. you do not draw the full area within the bounds despite claiming to be opaque) then you may get unexpected results due to the background not being redrawn.

Answer (score 6):

Opaque and transparent are opposite words.

A window, water, or air are transparent - you can see through them.

A wall, mud or concrete are opaque - you cannot see through them.

In terms of GUI programming, both JPanel and JComponent are opaque by default.  If you set them transparent, you are likely not to see much difference, since the underlying JFrame (or whatever) will usually be the same color as the JPanel/JComponent.

Comment: you are of course correct in what transparent and opaque mean in general, but the rest of this is misleading. Opaqueness in Swing is a special flag to indicate whether background painting behind a component is required, it does *not* in general affect how the component itself is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful reference is the section on [*Opacity*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) in the article [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html). It's also helpful to know that `JPanel` is [opaque by default](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) on many [L&Fs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), while `JLabel` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314).

Comment: `JPanel` may or may not be opaque by default. It depends upon which version of which PL&F is in effect.

Comment: +1, tutorials can always give a more complete explanation that we can, plus you learn some other interesting facts as well.

Comment: @camickr: Good point; I just learned that `JPanel` opacity depends on the L&F! :-)