# Java JPanel.setOpaque(false) doesn't make JPanel Transparent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I am trying to make a gui where I use a splitPane with stuff on the left and the main content on the right. I realized that when the splitPane gets resized the content from the right panel moves accordingly to fit the new size which is not the behavior I am looking for, I want the main content on the right to remain as is when I resize. So I used a layeredPane to add the main content behind a split pane that has stuff on the left and a transparent panel on the right to show the main content behind it.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
JPanel phantomPanel = new JPanel();
phantomPanel.setOpaque(false);
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, phantomPanel);

JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
rightPanel.setBounds(0,0,900,600);
splitPane.setBounds(0,0,900,600);
layeredPane.add(rightPanel,0,0); //Main Content is behind the split pane
layeredPane.add(splitPane, 1,0);
```

I am seeing the splitPane with the left panel as it should be but the right panel is white, switching the layers on the layeredPane I do see my (non white) main panel.

Changing the background color of the right panel I realized that the white is indeed the transparent panel and the problem is that the panel behind it isn't showing. What am I missing?

[The split Pane with the non transparent right panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKq5Y.png)
[What should show behind it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCJtS.png)

Comment: *"I realized that when the splitPane gets resized the content from the right panel moves accordingly to fit the new size which is not the behavior I am looking for, I want the main content on the right to remain as is when I resize"* - Put the "main" content into a `JScrollPane` instead

Comment: Does this question, using the links in the answers, help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416454/jpanel-said-to-be-opaque-what-does-that-mean

Comment: *I want the main content on the right to remain as is when I resize.* - use the `setResizeWeight(...)` method of the split pane to control how space is allocated when the frame size changes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried your suggestion but it seems that resizing the SplitPane still moves the ScrollPane around as opposed to clipping some of its content to still show the same view point

Comment: Edit your question and include a [mre] so we can see the problematic behavior for ourselves.  Currently, I am unable to understand why opacity and JLayeredPanes address the problem described in your first two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @VGR as I was making the minimal reproducible example I found the solution, both the transparent panel and the SplitPane need to be transparent in order for the Panel behind to show

```
package FrontEnd;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setBackground(Color.blue);

        JPanel transparent = new JPanel();
        transparent.setOpaque(false);

        JSplitPane SP = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,left,transparent);
        SP.setBounds(0,0,600,600);
        SP.setOpaque(false);

        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setBackground(Color.red);
        right.setBounds(0,0,600,600);

        JLayeredPane LP = new JLayeredPane();
        LP.add(right,0,0);
        LP.add(SP,1,0);

        frame.add(LP);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now theoretically the right panel (red) shouldn't move around when resizing the SplitPane as that affects the left panel and the transparent panel