# How do I use JLabels?

Tags: java, image, jlabel

When I try to create a JLabel, it displays text perfectly and is placed fine within the container, but if I try to add an image to the label, nothing shows up.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("../media/link_walk.png", "hh");
JLabel j = new JLabel("hello");
j.setIcon(icon);
p.add(j);
```

Comment: Does the panel p have a layout manager?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a JLabel's background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314/how-do-i-set-a-jlabels-background-color)

Comment: Yes, that stuff helped with the background color, but it still refuses to display an image.

Comment: you must add the icon to the JLabel for the image to be displayed. I see that you've commented that part out.

Comment: You should edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If your app. is in Jar files and the image is an application resource, it will also be in a Jar file.

The `ImageIcon` constructor that accepts a `String` presumes the `String` represents a file path/name.  A `File` object cannot be established to a resource in a Jar.  For resources in a Jar, it is necessary to access them by `URL`.

To get an `URL` to something in a Jar, use something like..

```
URL urlToImage = this.getClass().getResource("/media/link_walk.png");
// Check the URL!
System.out.println("urlToImage is " + urlToImage);
```

Then use the `ImageIcon` constructor that accepts an `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

JLabels are not opaque by default, and so background color changes won't be seen unless you make them opaque via setOpaque(true).  Also the preferredSize of the JLabel will depend on the text it holds.

Comment: See also [How do I set a JLabel's background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314).

Comment: @trash: thanks for that link.  This seems to be a fairly common problem.

Comment: It's a popular duplicate and the tip of the [`opaque`](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#props) property iceberg. :-)