# jLabels will not change color

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, simulator

I am developing a Sorting Algorithm Simulator in NetBeans using an applet. I have a Timer and a TimerTask. I want to change the background color of labels according to how they sort. The first run changes the colors but after that the colors don't change. I ran the program in debug mode and saw that after the first run a InterruptedException is thrown from the TimerTask. I have no idea why this is happening.

This is my TimerTask method which has the run() method in it.
Sorry if its lengthy code.

```
    private class AnimationUpdator extends TimerTask {
    JLabel[] values = {valuejLabel3, valuejLabel4, valuejLabel5, valuejLabel6, valuejLabel7,
        valuejLabel8, valuejLabel9, valuejLabel10, valuejLabel11, valuejLabel12};
    JLabel[] pointer = {pointerjLabel3, pointerjLabel4, pointerjLabel5, pointerjLabel6, pointerjLabel7,
        pointerjLabel8, pointerjLabel9, pointerjLabel10, pointerjLabel11, pointerjLabel12};
    JLabel[] okPointer = {okjLabel3, okjLabel4, okjLabel5, okjLabel6, okjLabel7,
        okjLabel8, okjLabel9, okjLabel10, okjLabel11};
    int runCount = 0;
    public void run() {
        if (order.equals("Ascending")) {
            if (i == 10) {
                pointer[i - 1].setVisible(false);
                jLabel3.setText("Sorted!!!");
                stop();
            } else {
                JLabel key = values[i];
                key.setBackground(Color.red);
                j = i - 1;
                int init = 0;
                pointer[i].setText("i-->");
                pointer[j].setText("j-->");
                pointer[i].setVisible(true);
                pointer[j].setVisible(true);

                while (j >= 0 && Integer.parseInt(values[j].getText()) > Integer.parseInt(key.getText())) {
                    values[j].setBackground(Color.blue);
                    insert.setLabel1x(values[j].getX());
                    insert.setLabel1y(values[j].getY());
                    if (swap) {
                        insert.setLabel2x(values[i].getX());
                        insert.setLabel2y(values[i].getY());
                    } else {
                        insert.setLabel2y(key.getY());
                        insert.setLabel2x(key.getX());
                    }
                    int xCounterForward = 0;
                    int xCounterBackward = 0;
                    int yCounter = 0;
                    for (int maincount = 0; maincount < 60; maincount++) {
                        onLoop = true;
                        if (xCounterForward < 20) {
                            insert.setLabel1x(values[j].getX() + 1);
                            if (init == 0) {
                                insert.setLabel2x(values[i].getX() - 1);
                            }
                            xCounterForward++;
                        } else if (xCounterForward == 20 && yCounter < 20) {
                            insert.setLabel1y(values[j].getY() + 1);
                            if (swap) {
                                insert.setLabel2y(values[i].getY() - 1);
                            } else {
                                insert.setLabel2y(key.getY() - 1);
                            }
                            yCounter++;
                        } else if (yCounter == 20 && xCounterBackward < 20) {
                            insert.setLabel1x(values[j].getX() - 1);
                            xCounterBackward++;
                        }
                        values[j].setLocation(insert.getLabel1x(), insert.getLabel1y());
                        if (swap) {
                            values[i].setLocation(insert.getLabel2x(), insert.getLabel2y());
                        } else {
                            key.setLocation(insert.getLabel2x(), insert.getLabel2y());
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(MS_TO_WAIT2);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    swap = false;
                    values[j + 1] = values[j];
                    init++;
                    pointer[j].setVisible(false);
                    j = j - 1;
                    if (j >= 0) {
                        pointer[j].setText("j-->");
                        pointer[j].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                if (j >= 0 && Integer.parseInt(values[j].getText()) < Integer.parseInt(key.getText())) {
                    values[j].setBackground(Color.green);
                    values[i].setBackground(Color.green);
                    okPointer[j].setText("Ok");
                    okPointer[j].setVisible(true);
                }
                if (j == -1) {
                    values[j + 1].setBackground(Color.green);
                    values[i].setBackground(Color.green);
                    okPointer[j + 1].setText("Ok");
                    okPointer[j + 1].setVisible(true);
                }
                if (onLoop) {
                    for (int maincount = 0; maincount < 20; maincount++) {
                        insert.setLabel2x(key.getX() + 1);
                        insert.setLabel2y(key.getY());
                        key.setLocation(insert.getLabel2x(), insert.getLabel2y());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(MS_TO_WAIT2);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                values[j + 1] = key;
                onLoop = false;
                i++;
                if (j >= 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(MS_TO_WAIT2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    okPointer[j].setVisible(false);
                    pointer[j].setVisible(false);
                } else if (j == -1) {
                    okPointer[j + 1].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your code (only, don't do a code dump) that you're having problems with

Comment: Better yet, write a small program that uses a timer and timertask to change the color of labels 3-4 times -- that will illustrate your problem without involving a bunch of other code, and quite possibly show you where your problem is without needing us. THEN your question can be specific, and we can help you without having to wade through a lot of other code that's not relevant to the problem.  Even if we don't use NetBeans...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a JLabel's background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314/how-do-i-set-a-jlabels-background-color)

Comment: *"I have a Timer and a TimerTask"* This would seem to be your first mistake. Use either a javax.swing.Timer or SwingWorker to ensure all updates to the UI are performed within the context of the EDT. I don't see the point of the sleeps, that's kind of the point of the timer...I also don't see a repaint call anywhere...