# Bind single event to all JLabels in Java

Tags: java, swing, events

I have 20 `JLabels` and all of them have to change their background color when mouse enters and change back to original color when mouse outs.

Do I have to individually bind 2 Event-listeners of `MouseEntered` and `MouseExited` with all `JLabel`s separately, or is there any work around so I can make just 2 events kind of monitoring all `JLabel`s?

Like in the image below: there are about 6 `JLabels` and I want each one to change its background color whenever the mouse enters the scene and change back to original color when the mouse outs.

[image]

So, do I have to individually set event listeners on all `JLabels`, or there can be a single event listener for all `JLabels`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register all 20 JLabels with the same mouse listener. You would do something like this:

```
MouseListener m = new MouseAdapter() // create our own mouse listener
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
    {
         e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.RED);; // this method changes the colours of all the labels
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.GREEN); // this method changes the colours back to normal
    }
};
for (JLabel label: labels) // iterate over all the labels
{
    label.addMouseListener(m); // give them all our mouse listener
}
```

Where "labels" is some collection (List, Set, array...) of your JLabels, and changeLabelColours() and  changeLabelColoursBack() are two methods that you define to change the colours.

hope this helps!

EDIT: reading your edited question, I think I should point out that this code will cause *ALL* labels to change colour when *ANY* of the labels is moused-over. I think that's what you mean.

Comment: This could be really useful in the very near future for me. Thanks! +1.
What if a slightly different mouse listener was needed for each JLabel? How would you do it individually?

Comment: Iterating is showing some error. would you look at that please?

Comment: Ok let me give it a try hold on

Comment: Joehot200: if you wanted to define object-specific behaviour for each object, you can use anonymous classes to do it: something like `for (JLabel label: labels){ label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {...}) }` this would give each label it's own, individual listener, and any functions overridden in the {...} block can use `label` to refer to the individual label.

Comment: Abdul Jabbar WebBestow: remember, you will need to provide your own collection of your JLabels; my code posted there will not function on it's own. Also, if you want individual behavior per label, see my comment above.

Comment: Nekojimi I addedMouseListener to all of JLabels and listner is working good just like you said but how can I change color of JLabel? for testing this I wrote this line System.out.println("Mouse Entered"); and its working but how can I change label color

Comment: Try `JLabel.setBackground(Color bg)`

Comment: Noop Not working. I also tried putting just setBackground but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "make events". You make eventListeners. And yes, you can do just 2 event listeners and bound them to all `JLabel`s.

Or, if you prefer, you can extends `Jlabel` into `MyJlabel`, that has the event listener built in, and save yourself from the repeated binding, if it bothers you.

Comment: @Nekojimi just did that above. His answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one MouseListener reference.

You should differentiate event sources based on references or on component name.

Here is an example

```
final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label1");
label1.setName("label1");
final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label2");
label2.setName("label2");
final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("label3");
label3.setName("label3");

MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // you can check references
    if(e.getSource() == label1) {
      System.out.println("exited " + label1.getName());
    } else if (e.getSource() == label2) {
      System.out.println("exited " + label2.getName());
    } else if (e.getSource() == label3) {
      System.out.println("exited " + label3.getName());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    String name = ((JComponent)e.getSource()).getName();
    // or you can check name of component
    switch (name) {
      case "label1":
      case "label2":
      case "label3":
        System.out.println("entered " + name);
        break;
    }
  }
};
for (JLabel l : Arrays.asList(label1, label2, label3)) {
  l.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that labels need to be [opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2380328/878469) in order to change their bg color.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class CrazyLabels extends JFrame {

    public CrazyLabels() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        add(content);
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));        

        MouseAdapter listener = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
                label.setBackground(Color.red);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
                label.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Label.background"));
            }

        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JLabel label = new MyLabel(listener);
            label.setText("---- label ----");
            content.add(label);
        }

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new CrazyLabels().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyLabel extends JLabel {
        public MyLabel(MouseListener listener) {
            setOpaque(true);
            addMouseListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example a single listener is used to enforce behavior in all labels.