# properties of scala swing elements

Tags: swing, scala, background

In the following scala code I change foreground, horizontalAlignment and background to some values. However in the GUI these properties are not shown.

The horizontalAlignment remains centered.
The backgrould remains gray.
However the foreground (font color) changes according to the values.
How can I obtain the desired effects?

Thanks for any help!

```
import scala.swing._

object GuiTest extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Label Test"
    val tempList = List("Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin")
    contents = bagPnl(tempList)
    val fields = contents(0).peer.getComponents
    val valuefields
    = for (f <- 0 until fields.length / 2)
     yield tempList(f) -> fields.apply(2 * f + 1).asInstanceOf[javax.swing.JLabel]
     val tfm = valuefields.toMap[String, javax.swing.JLabel]
     tfm.apply("Celsius").setText("35°C")
     tfm.apply("Kelvin").setText("0 K")
  }

  def bagPnl(list: List[String]) = new GridBagPanel {
    val gbc = new Constraints
    gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3)
    var l = 0
    for (title <- list) {
      gbc.gridy = l
      gbc.gridx = 0
      /* title label */
      add(new Label {
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Left
        foreground = java.awt.Color.RED
        background = java.awt.Color.CYAN
        text = title
      }, gbc)
      gbc.gridx = 1
      /* value label */
      val t = new Label {
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Right
        foreground = java.awt.Color.BLUE
        background = java.awt.Color.YELLOW
        name = title
      }
      t.background = java.awt.Color.GREEN
      add(t, gbc)
      l = l + 1
    }
  }
}
```

sorry I am not allowed to post images yet :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` is one hell of a layout manager. You'll be probably better of with `GroupLayout`, but there is no related panel type in Scala-Swing yet. ([Here](https://github.com/Sciss/SwingPlus/blob/master/src/test/scala/de/sciss/swingplus/GroupPanelTest.scala) for an example).

The problem with the **label positioning** is that its alignment only makes sense when it is given more space than its preferred size. By default, the grid bag layout doesn't give it more space, and the centering is a result of its own alignment (not that of the label). The easiest here is to specify that the components can use up the horizontal space if available:

```
gbc.fill = GridBagPanel.Fill.Horizontal
```

The second questions concerns the **background color of the label**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314/how-do-i-set-a-jlabels-background-color) is a related question. In short, by default the label is transparent and its background color ignored. You can switch to opaque painting:

```
new Label {
  ...
  opaque = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
yes setting opaque = true helps
and I found out after setting preferredSize to a Dimension the labels are aligned.
And I agree GridBagLayout is not the easiest layout manager.

Comment: Glad it works. If your question is solved, you should mark it by checking the answer.