# JLabel in JScrollPane background does not change

Tags: java, swing, background, jlabel, jscrollpane

I would like to change the background of my `JLabel` in a `JScrollPane`'s `RowHeaderView`.

```
JLabel jl = new JLabel("asdfasdfasdf");
jl.setForeground(Color.RED);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

// I Have tried
jl.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
scroll.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
scroll.setOpaque(true);
scroll.setVisible(true);

scroll.setRowHeaderView(jl);
```

However the text is red but the background remains white.

**EDIT**

This is a duplicate of [How do I set a JLabel's background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314/how-do-i-set-a-jlabels-background-color), however I cannot set this question as a duplicate myself as I require 250 rep.

Comment: `jl.setOpaque(true);` ??

Comment: Oh... no... I missed that out.. Please answer below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314/how-do-i-set-a-jlabels-background-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Opaque for the JLabel is false. which means not visible.
use jl.setOpaque(true);

good luck.