# How to change JLabel background when I click the JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to change my JLabel background to blue using mouseClicked. The name of my JLabel is lblKembali. I tried this code and when I tried to click the label it didnt change the background. Please help. Thank you.

```
lblKembali = new JLabel("Kembali");
lblKembali.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,30));
lblKembali.setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());    
lblKembali.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    lblKembali.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try making  your  `JLabel` opaque : `lblKembali.setOpaque(true)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a JLabel's background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380314/how-do-i-set-a-jlabels-background-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a JLabel is non-opaque so its background is not painted. You need to make the label opaque when you create it:

```
lblKembali = new JLabel("Kembali");
lblKembali.setOpaque( true );
```

Also you can make your listener more generic so it can be shared by multiple components by doing:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    Component c = e.getComponent();
    c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
```